# Windows 8 IE 10 Handwriting Insert Input Browser Event

Tags: input, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

I've written an application that uses keypress on a text input  to trigger activating and deactivating a button.  One of my users is using the handwriting function on a Windows 8 tablet to input text. He writes the text in, then hits the Insert button.   The text gets inserted, but doesn't fire the keypress event.  It also doesn't fire the onchange or onpaste events.

Does anyone know if there's an event that can be caught that will allow me to validate the form element?  I can put an onchange event on it and then click out of the box, which will trigger the validation, but that's not intuitive.

Here's the JQuery code I tried for the change event, but I'm open to using run of the mill JS to get the job done.

```
    var lastTerms ="";
    $("input#searchbox").change(function()
    {
    var acTerm = $("#searchbox").val(); 
        if (acTerm.length>2)
        {
           if (isDisabled($("#btnSearch")))
            {
                $("#btnSearch").removeClass("buttonDisabled");
                $("#btnSaveSearch").removeClass("buttonDisabled");
            }
        }
        else
        {
                            if (!isDisabled($("#btnSearch")))
            {
                $("#btnSearch").addClass("buttonDisabled");
                //$("#btnSaveSearch").addClass("buttonDisabled");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried using MS Pointer and gesture events? It is their alternative proposal to the W3C for touch events. It supports pen input. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673557(v=vs.85).aspx#Feature_detection . onPointerDown may be useful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771909(v=vs.85).aspx